# how to display largest and smallest in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I display both the `smallest` and `largest` on a single plot.

My current code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

smallest = lsoas.sort_values('imd_score').head(10)

largest = lsoas.sort_values('imd_score').head(10)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6, 6))
lsoas.plot(facecolor='black', linewidth=0.025, ax=ax)
smallest.plot(alpha=1, facecolor='red', linewidth=0, ax=ax)
largest.plot(alpha=1, facecolor='blue', linewidth=0, ax=ax)
ax.set_axis_off()
f.suptitle('Areas with smallest population')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

but this only shows the `largest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your code isn't exactly reproducible (`lsoas` is not defined), it appears you're setting both `smallest` and `largest` to `head(10)`, so they're defined as the same thing. Use `tail(10)` for the smallest value.

Comment: Oh thank you so much Perfi, you really helped. It works.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Could you please mark this as answered, then?